# How Do I Set The Garbage Collector For The AJC Ant Task?

Tags: ant, aspectj

I am getting out of memory errors when doing compile time weaving. As you can see, I have already set the Xmx (via maxmem) to 1024m. This could be due to the jar I am trying to weave is ~70MB.

How do I set the Garbage Collector? I tried using the X param but when I connect to the process with JConsole the ConcMarkSweep is not set.

```
    <echo message="Weaving..."/>
    <aspectj:iajc classpathref="compile.libs" aspectpath="${src.dir}" outJar="${output.jar}" fork="true" maxmem="1024m" X="+UseConcMarkSweepGC">
        <inpath>
            <pathelement path="${classes.dir}"/>
        </inpath>
    </aspectj:iajc>
```

The error is:

```
Bugs for exceptions thrown have titles File:line from the top stack, 
e.g., "SomeFile.java:243"

If you don't find the exception below in a bug, please add a new bug
at http://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=AspectJ
To make the bug a priority, please include a test program
that can reproduce this exception.
GC overhead limit exceeded

when weaving classes 
when weaving 
when batch building BuildConfig[null] #Files=0 AopXmls=#0
GC overhead limit exceeded
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
    at org.aspectj.apache.bcel.classfile.ConstantPool.copy(ConstantPool.java:69)
    at org.aspectj.apache.bcel.generic.ClassGen.<init>(ClassGen.java:161)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.LazyClassGen.<init>(LazyClassGen.java:255)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelObjectType.getLazyClassGen(BcelObjectType.java:523)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWeaver.weave(BcelWeaver.java:1742)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWeaver.weaveWithoutDump(BcelWeaver.java:1710)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWeaver.weaveAndNotify(BcelWeaver.java:1472)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWeaver.weave(BcelWeaver.java:1286)
    at org.aspectj.ajdt.internal.compiler.AjPipeliningCompilerAdapter.weaveQueuedEntries(AjPipeliningCompilerAdapter.java:435)
    at org.aspectj.ajdt.internal.compiler.AjPipeliningCompilerAdapter.afterCompiling(AjPipeliningCompilerAdapter.java:304)
    at org.aspectj.ajdt.internal.compiler.CompilerAdapter.ajc$afterReturning$org_aspectj_ajdt_internal_compiler_CompilerAdapter$2$f9cc9ca0(CompilerAdapter.aj:73)
    at org.aspectj.org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:430)
    at org.aspectj.ajdt.internal.core.builder.AjBuildManager.performCompilation(AjBuildManager.java:1003)
    at org.aspectj.ajdt.internal.core.builder.AjBuildManager.performBuild(AjBuildManager.java:267)
    at org.aspectj.ajdt.internal.core.builder.AjBuildManager.batchBuild(AjBuildManager.java:181)
    at org.aspectj.ajdt.ajc.AjdtCommand.doCommand(AjdtCommand.java:112)
    at org.aspectj.ajdt.ajc.AjdtCommand.runCommand(AjdtCommand.java:60)
    at org.aspectj.tools.ajc.Main.run(Main.java:355)
    at org.aspectj.tools.ajc.Main.runMain(Main.java:234)
    at org.aspectj.tools.ajc.Main.main(Main.java:84)

23-Sep-2013 23:58:12 org.aspectj.weaver.tools.Jdk14Trace info
INFO: Dumping to D:\Projects\Delete\AspectjTest\.\ajcore.20130923.234357.932.txt

1 fail|abort
```

Answer (score 1):

a workaround would be to use the `<java>` ant command, and list the main weaver class as the thing that runs. `org.aspectj.tools.ajc.Main`, you would also have to set all the args manually that this ant task does automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I got it using it via ANTs `exec` task calling the **`aspectj1.7/bin/ajc.bat`** (`1.7.3`) with args.
Just editing `ajc.bat` and replacing `-Xmx64g` by **`-Xmx3g`** helped me trying to apply it e.g. on the `guava-18.0.jar`.

Similarly it was also mentioned here: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=36234#c3

if you wan't to use the **`aspectj:iajc`** task nevertheless you should run your **`ant.bat`** (or sh) with the **appropriate JVM args** as above.

Within **Eclipse** (it happens normally within the Eclipse VM and in case it is not appropriately configured and you don't wanna make the JVM arg changes in the **`eclipse.ini`** file) you would need to adjust the implicitely created **`External Tools Configuration` for your ANT target and set `JRE => Runtime JRE: [x] Separate JRE: ...`** and adjust its **`VM arguments: -Xmx3g`** e.g..